# How to /setblock a powered repeater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

Trying to /setblock a powered repeater, my questions are:

1. How do I setblock a powered repeater?
2. If I setblock a powered repeater, will it take 1 tick to power the block in front of it or will it instantly power the block in front of it (on the same tick that the repeater is set)?
3. I'm trying to setblock a redstone device that both powers the block in front of it and unpowers itself the tick after it is set - should I use powered repeaters or powered comparators?

Comment: You could use an observer, they emit 1-tick pulses on a a block update, and power off after the tick, you could then use commands or a button or something to update the observer to activate your circuit

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can, but you could just `/setblock` a repeater in front of a redstone block. Or you could use `/data` to modify its NBT data.